# In the sentence “ "" is used to represent an empty string in programming languages” should we capitalize the “i” in “is”, and why or why not?

Tags: capitalization, symbols

In the sentence:

> "" is used to represent an empty string in programming languages.

Should we capitalize *i* in *is*, and why or why not?

Comment: Your example is not a sentence but just a verb phrase that is part of a sentence.

Comment: @BillJ Sorry, I don't know the difference between sentence and verb phrase, but the point is we use `'' is used to represent an empty string.` in the beginning of sentence, and I want to know if we should ever capitalize `i` and why?

Comment: @BillJ: No, it's a full sentence, it's just that the subject is '' (i.e. it might be read out as "Quote-quote is used to represent...").

Comment: @IvanIvanyuk Is the " notation intended to represent a subject? If it is, then I wouldn't capitalise the "i". Btw, is this to do with computer coding?

Comment: @BillJ yes, `''` represents subject, and it is related to computer coding

Comment: In that case, " represents the first element of the sentence, so I can't see any obvious reason to capitalise "I".

Comment: The Gricean maxim of manner is satisfied by << The symbol ' ' is used to represent an empty string. >> 'Symbol-as-a-word' is a far more obscure device than 'word-as-a-word' (referring to the use-mention distinction).

Comment: As usual, @EdwinAshworth takes the long view and shows us that a little rewording helps the reader. We're not stuck with the problem of whether to capitalize the word **is** in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: Whether it's a valid sentence is opinion-based, and if it's invalid then you can capitalize anything you want. It's the same as " is used to represent happy." *The New Yorker* will chase you out of town on a haycart for such a thing (an emoji in a sentence), but if you accept that it's valid to use non-alphanumeric characters in a sentence, then it's the logical punctuation. Whether it's acceptable is a matter of opinion. A more formal alternative would be "A pair of single quotation marks ('') is used..."

Comment: I agree with @StuartF -- I would specify that this is a pair of single quotes so there is no confusion with one double-quote mark.

Comment: `' '` is used to represent an empty string.

Comment: @TinfoilHat <pedantic> That's not an empty string, it's a string containing a single space character.

Comment: @Barmar — Inadvertent space; do-over: `''` is used to represent an empty string.

Comment: A change of the question has made many of these comments seem strange.

Comment: @BillJ So, if I understand correctly, we should capitalize only first word, and since `""` is a first word, `is` should not be capitalized. Can somebody add answer to question, so that I could accept it(preferably with links to some reputable sources, like dictionaries or something, I don't have expertise in this topic, so don't know which sources are reputable)

Comment: You can also invert the sentence: "An empty string is represented by a pair of single quotation marks ('')". In this context, especially if you don't have total control of the font and typesetting, I might even given the ASCII character code of the symbol in brackets. I've seen too many cases of things getting mangled by too-clever software switching to left amd right quotes.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin 'the long view' as opposed to 'the narrow view'. Interesting opposites. But a friendlier description than 'frame challenge', and 'broad view' nuances a lack of precision:)